# log4net: Where to place static LogManger object? (using it in different projects of a solution, each having an individual config-file)

Tags: c#, .net, logging, config, log4net

So far I did not get in touch with config-files. So, relating to that, I think I miss some basic knowledge to completely understand, when using log4net the first time.

---

This is what I already read:

https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging

https://csharp.today/log4net-tutorial-great-library-for-logging

[log4net configuration with [assembly:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648813/log4net-configuration-with-assembly)

---

Lets say we got three different types of projects in a solution, each having log4net attached:

- Project MidLevel: .NET Framework 4.6.1 (using LowLevel)
- Project LowLevel: .NET Standard 2.0
- Project Application: .NET Framework 4.6.1 (using LowLevel and MidLevel)

1) Where exactly shall I place the following lines? In each class where I want to log?

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log 
       = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

2) I wondered how I get static object above everywhere where I want to use it. So I added a class like the following into project LowLevel, hoping just a 'using' could help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using log4net;

namespace LowLevel.NuGet.Log4Net
{
    public class Log4Net
    {
        // Avoiding overhead by logging, reducing use of CPU via static LogManager object.
        private static readonly log4net.ILog _log
            = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        //
        // Properties
        //

        public static log4net.ILog Log { get => _log; }
    }
}
```

But I suggest I wont work, because a .NET Standard 2.0 project hasn't got its own config-file.

- Am I am right? (Of course I will check this on my own, too. But it might be helpful if you point me in advance, to knowledge I am missing at the moment.)
- How is it possible to create just one static LogManager object, using it in every project?
- Will mentioned static LogManger object use different config-files of each individual project then? And if not, how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: _"How is it possible to create just one static LogManager object"_ You don't. That's the point. It's static. BTW: I'd use `typeof(ClassName)` instead of that ugly reflection. You then have _one_ config in the Project Application. If you want to have different configs for the different parts, you'll do that by using the namespaces. That way you can define different loggers for e.g. `my.prj.App.*` and `my.prj.Mid.*` and `my.prj.Low.*` Lookup "named hierarchy" in here => https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html

Comment: To the points 1) and 2): Yes you put it in every class that will log. If you are using Dependency Injection, you can inject logger instances. If you are always ever want to use the root logger, you could create one static Logger, but I really do not recommend that. You'll miss out on some neat features that go with specific class loggers, for example you'll only be able to set one global log level.

Comment: You seem to have a misconception about what the `LogManager` is in contrast to `Logger` instances. The `LogManager` _is_ a static sort-of-factory, that creates `Logger` instances for you. If you make those `private static readonly`, all instances of the class share the same `Logger` instance.

Comment: I think I did not write it clearly. Of course I did not mean to use just one object at a single place. But i kept in mind, that those object are static so they practically don't differ.

Comment: Thank you, Fildor. You gave me several points to follow and think about.

Comment: Fildor, regarding to your 3rd commend: If you follow the first link I gave, then you will see this code-line, I wrote above, again as a recommendation. But again, many thanks to you! I have to think about it.

Comment: Yes, he recommends it. I don't know why. Maybe it's just me or him being lazy. In the examples at log4net, you'll see `typeof` used. You can even define macros in VS that will create that line with the class name filled in ... so, that's probably opinionated.

Comment: Fildor,  I am satisfied with this information you gave me. Just write down those options using typeof so I can give you points.

Comment: Done, hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1 : LogManager.GetLogger

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I really don't know why Matt suggests this abomination (imho). Yes, you can simply copy&paste it in every class from which you want to log, but reflection is *slow*.

Despite the fact, that LogManager should give you the same instance of `Logger` for the the same class, it *is* recommended to make it static, to avoid calls to LogManager. This should increase performance especially if you have logging classes that are instantiated very often.

In log4net docs (and what I'd do naturally) the alternative way is to do it this way:

`private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassName));`

Downside: You have a classname in there, so no simple C&P.

**BUT** Visual Studio will change it if you change the class name using the refactor functionality and you can define shortcut/templates to fill in the classname automagically. But even if you do it manually, I'd still prefer this over reflection.

For reference: [typeof operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) and [lang-reference: typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-typeof-operator)

## Part 2 : Config

It doesn't really make sense to have the logging config with the libraries. They won't be executed "standalone". What you will do instead is utilize namespaces.

Given, you have libs A and B, with namespaces "my.prj.A" and "my.prj.B" and a "Main" App "my.prj.App", then you'll have one config in the App. You can however still apply different settings / appenders:

log4net spans a tree of configuration inheritance (as documented in their "configuration" and "getting started" documents). So, you will *always* have a root logger. This is the default or fallback, if no other logger applies.

Then you can define sub-loggers (my term, not sure what they call them), for example:

- logger "my.prj" which will apply to all loggers created from `typeof(my.prj.*.SomeClass)` if no more specific logger applies. Doesn't make sense? Yes, it does - it will *not* apply to for example 3rd party libs. If they happen to use log4net, they will fall back to root.
- logger "my.prj.A" will apply to all classes from library A.
- logger "my.prj.B.SomeFeatureNamespace" will apply to all classes from `FeatureNamespace` in library B.

... you get the gist.

**BTW:** Using `... = LogManager.GetLogger("MySuperSpecialLogger");` you can define one config for a "MySuperSpecialLogger", which comes in handy while debugging, because you can "follow" some flow across classes and can easily filter logs by logger name or have it write to a different file etc.
Or you can aggregate loginput for documentation. For example, you'd have 3 methods for login, but you need a log of attempts and success / fail : You can make a named logger for that and hook it up to its own appender, get it in the 3 implementations, write log output for login attempts/success/fail - done.

---

Having *no* config with the libs has some other effects, too:

- if you actually reuse them, each solution can define different logging configs for them.
- you can turn off logging in unit-test projects.
- if you (or someone else) use them in a project that uses a different logging framework, you *may* be able to still log but configs may come through a facade or adapter.